# Real sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $\sum a_nb_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there no correct answer to this question?

> [image]

For (a) and (c), I can take $a_n=0$ for all n, so $b_n$ can be unbounded. For (d), $a_n=0,1,0,2,0,3,...$  and $b_n=1,0,2,0,3,0,...$ shows both sequences can be unbounded.

So, is there no correct option or am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: Your works looks right to me; where is this question from?

Comment: Entrance exam For MSc math, Univ. of Hyderabad.